# jQuery Script Not Updating Form Input Value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple table with 2 text inputs and 2 non input cells. I have a script that runs when the first input field is modified which queries a database and then updates the other 3 cells in the same row. It is currently only updating the last 2 non input cells in the row and not the other input field in that row.

Here's an example of my table/scripts:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#addRow").click(function() {
    var markup = "<tr><td><input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control serialNumber\" autocomplete=\"off\" placeholder=\"Serial Number\" name=\"serialNumber[]\" value=\"\"></td><td><input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control assetID\" autocomplete=\"off\" placeholder=\"Asset ID\" name=\"assetID[]\" value=\"\"></td></td><td class=\"productCode\"></td><td class=\"description\"></td><td class=\"text-center deleteRow\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-trash\"></span></td></tr>";
    $("#shipmentItems").append(markup);
  });

  // Find and remove selected table rows

  $("#shipmentItems").on("click", ".deleteRow", function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('change', '.form-control.serialNumber', function() {

    var serialNumber = $(this).val();
    //console.log( recid );
    // Create a reference to $(this) here:
    $this = $(this);

    ID = 'ABC123';
    code = 'PC8765';
    description = 'Acme Standard Widget';

    $this.closest('tr').children('.form-control.assetID').val(ID);
    $this.closest('tr').children('.code').html(code);
    $this.closest('tr').children('.description').html(description);

  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="shipmentItems" class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col" width="20%">Serial</th>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col" width="15%">ID</th>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col" width="15%">Code</th>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col" width="45%">Description</th>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col" width="5%"></th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control serialNumber" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Serial Number" name="serialNumber[]" value=""></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control assetID" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Asset ID" name="assetID[]" value=""></td>
      <td class="code"></td>
      <td class="description"></td>
      <td class="deleteRow"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button type="button" name="addRow" value="addRow" id="addRow" class="btn btn-primary">Add Asset</button> &nbsp; &nbsp;
```

I've hardcoded the variables to be used in this example so there's no issue of there not being a value to replace for the 2nd input field. For some reason the 2nd input field is not updating here.

Comment: I think the issue is due to the fact that the **form-control assetID** is not a child of the TR element you are grabbing. In the case of the two non-input columns, they are direct children and can be accessed.

Comment: Use `.find()` instead of `.children()`. Then it will search anywhere in the TR, not just the direct children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inputs are not children of the tr, they're grandchildren, so `$this.children()` doesn't select them. Use `.find()` instead.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#addRow").click(function() {
    var markup = "<tr><td><input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control serialNumber\" autocomplete=\"off\" placeholder=\"Serial Number\" name=\"serialNumber[]\" value=\"\"></td><td><input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control assetID\" autocomplete=\"off\" placeholder=\"Asset ID\" name=\"assetID[]\" value=\"\"></td></td><td class=\"productCode\"></td><td class=\"description\"></td><td class=\"text-center deleteRow\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-trash\"></span></td></tr>";
    $("#shipmentItems").append(markup);
  });

  // Find and remove selected table rows

  $("#shipmentItems").on("click", ".deleteRow", function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('change', '.form-control.serialNumber', function() {

    var serialNumber = $(this).val();
    //console.log( recid );
    // Create a reference to $(this) here:
    $this = $(this);

    ID = 'ABC123';
    code = 'PC8765';
    description = 'Acme Standard Widget';

    $this.closest('tr').find('.form-control.assetID').val(ID);
    $this.closest('tr').children('.code').html(code);
    $this.closest('tr').children('.description').html(description);

  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="shipmentItems" class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col" width="20%">Serial</th>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col" width="15%">ID</th>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col" width="15%">Code</th>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col" width="45%">Description</th>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col" width="5%"></th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control serialNumber" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Serial Number" name="serialNumber[]" value=""></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control assetID" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Asset ID" name="assetID[]" value=""></td>
      <td class="code"></td>
      <td class="description"></td>
      <td class="deleteRow"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button type="button" name="addRow" value="addRow" id="addRow" class="btn btn-primary">Add Asset</button> &nbsp; &nbsp;
```